# "Couldn't find Instalable ISAM" VB6 Data Control to Access DB

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2010

I've just been handed an old VB6 application that uses DataControls on the form; these are referencing an MDB file (Access 2000 or 2002-2003) and have the "Connect" property set to "Access 2000;"
Machine has recently been upgraded (Windows 7, MS Office 2010) and is now giving "Couldn't find installable ISAM" at Form load. I've read quite a bit of information regarding this issue, but I've had no luck resolving it.

- I'm not sure how (or whether I should) install the missing ISAM drivers.
- I've tried changing the "Connect" property of the DataControl to "Access" only (no 2000) but then I get "unrecognisable database format error".
- I've tried updating the DB to Access 2010 (.accdb) format with the same problem "unrecognisable database format".
- I've tried creating a Database connection and assigning that to the DataControl control "Connect" property: doesn't work and I'm not even sure this is a valid thing to do.

Has anyone seen and resolved this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what a "DataNavigator" is, and I've been around VB6 for a long time.  Can I confirm that you are not talking about one of the native Data controls and calling it a "DataNavigator"?

Comment: Yes, sorry I think it is a naïve "Data Control", specifically the one on the form is the control with backward/forward navigation arrows at either end for row selection. Post updated

Comment: Ok.  Next thing is that there are different data controls which meet your description.  Which one is yours?   The ADO Data control or the older one?

Comment: p.s. How big a job is it to get rid of the data controls in your project, assuming you know what to do?

Comment: Can you check your references (under Projects | References) - are there any objects marked as "MISSING" - you might need to update your references - or register an older DAO library

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/155666 gives some insight into the problem, by explaining why this error comes up.  It's a version problem between your version of Access and your data control as it's set up.  The solution is to either set up the control differently or (definitely a plan B) change your way of handling data access to something more robust.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I managed to resolve programmatically, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I never got to the bottom of why the Data Control was unable to connect to the hardcoded database path; however I managed to resolve the issue by opening the database and assigning the required recordsets programmatically within the Form.Load event.
i.e.

```
dbPath = App.Path & "\XXX.mdb"
Set daoDB = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase(dbPath) 

Set rsBS = daoDB.OpenRecordset(--Table data to retrieve--, dbOpenDynaset)
Set Databs.Recordset = rsBS

Set rsLiq = daoDB.OpenRecordset(--Table data to retrieve--, dbOpenDynaset)
Set DataLiq.Recordset = rsLiq
```

Works fine.